# Setting base packages for scan in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring boot 2.0.6.RELEASE in my multi module project.
In module module-common I have bot document

```
package com.entity;

@Document(collection = "bot")
public class Bot{
  @Id
  protected String id;
  protected String name;
  //getters and setters
}
```

In another module first-module I have

```
package com.first.entity;

@Document(collection = "bot")
@TypeAlias("FirstBotType")
public class FirstBot extends Bot {
  private String fieldInFirstBot;
  //getter and setter
}
```

In master-module I have dependencies on both modules and start app:

```
package com.bots;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com")
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also I have repository:

```
public interface BotRepository extends MongoRepository<Bot, String> { }
```

When I'm querying `repository.findAll()` it returns list, which contains only `Bot` instances instead of `FirstBot`.
I can fix it by providing a bean, which extends `AbstractMongoConfiguration`, implement all methods and override `getMappingBasePackages()`:

```
@Override
protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
  return Arrays.asList("com.entity", "com.first.entity");
}
```

Is there any way to avoid creating `AbstractMongoConfiguration` bean manually and tell spring boot to scan packages I need?

Update: I added `@EntityScan("com")` annotation but nothing changed

Comment: I'm afraid you have to declare MongoConfig bean that extends `AbstractMongoConfiguration`